# Essbase Webservices for Authentication

Tags: web-services, essbase

I want to connect to Essbase from a 3rd Party App - Alteryx. Essbase exposes JAVA APIs and allows 3rd party apps to connect to those JAVA APIs. However, Alteryx cannot connect to those APIs and hence I am interested in knowing about the SOAP based Essbase Webservices.

Does anyone know how to call Essbase Authentication webservice complete with attributes such as URL and request body.
In case if anyone has a working sample that can be shared, please post it or otherwise, kindly point to a web resource that can be referred to fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using the SOAP-based Essbase web services. They are a dead end with almost zero documentation. You can just use the normal Essbase Java API, which can be configured to use HTTP. There are numerous examples on the web as well as sample Java examples that ship with Essbase.